# OSGi and Java EE - JOSGiEE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, osgi

After reading [this article](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/soa-talk/osgi-and-future-directions-for-enterprise-java/), one question came to my mind: 'Is OSGi becoming a Java EE? Is OSGi going to replace Java EE? Is OSGi incrementing Java EE?' 
It's true that historically OSGi is totally different from Java EE, but considering now the resulting work from the EEG, some of these services are Java EE services. 
Another fact is that who uses Java EE uses it for its APIs in contradiction to OSGi which is supposed to be API agnostic.

I am not sure where is it going to get, what about you guys?

Comment: Hey @ArjanTijms, why the historical revisionism? At the time of the question "Java EE" was known as J2EE. It's more confusing now to go back and rename everything.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Actually, Java EE is the official term since late 2006/ early 2007. It predates every question on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: @ArjanTijms Frankly that's pretty much irrelevant as almost everybody still knows it as J2EE. Anyway I just don't get the point of attempting to edit J2EE out of history.

Comment: @NeilBartlett >almost everybody still knows it as J2EE - Hopefully this will thus change ;) For some 6 years it has been the wrong term to use. Note that SO itself also renames it automatically (notice that the tag of this post is "java-ee" which was done by SO), I'm just helping with the manual cases. There are still a great number of legitimate uses of the term (mainly historical) and of course I never edit those.

Answer (score 3):

OSGi is the container technology. It has nothing to do with Java EE technologies like (for example) Servlets, JDBC, EJBs, JMS etc.

It looks after the packaging of the code components (into bundles) and the management thereof. That may impact how you package a solution (e.g. you may not use a .ear or a .war) but the APIs you're used to programming to won't change.

Comment: but J2EE containers are also called "containers", aren't they? There is definitely an amount of overlap. Spring DM Server is n OSGI alternative to packaging enterprise applications. There are also issues with Hibernate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662986/osgi-hibernate, so I'd say the question is spot-on.

Answer (score 2):

It already exists if you want to try it: [IBM WebSphere Application Server 6.1: Componentization Overview](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/topic/com.ibm.iea.was_v6/was/6.1/Architecture/WASv61_Componentization/player.html?dmuid=20061227202131422194&noframes=true). I thought BEA and JBoss implementations were in the works, but I haven't heard anything recently.

OSGi won't be a replacement for Java EE - it extends it by adding a plugin framework. Whether it becomes part of a future Java EE standard probably depends on what happens with [any Sun acquisition](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/03/18/ibm_buying_sun/), the future of [Project Jigsaw](http://blogs.oracle.com/mr/entry/jigsaw) (replacement for [JSR 277](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=277)), and probably a few factors I don't know about. There aren't any plans for [Java EE 6](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316), except to cross fingers and hope something makes it into [Java Standard Edition 7](https://jdk7.dev.java.net/).

Comment: re IBM W..Overview: Topic Not Found

Answer (score 2):

I like the term [OS-JEE-i](http://www.jroller.com/habuma/entry/os_jee_i).

Answer (score 2):

OSGi is not becoming J2EE... I'm not sure what that would even mean! It is adding features that help to migrate J2EE code more smoothly to OSGi. But they are optional features, there is no need to use them if you do not have Java EE legacy.

Perhaps a better question is whether OSGi will become the widely accepted deployment container for Java applications, as J2EE once was. IMHO the answer is clearly yes.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at InfoQ article about new buzzword [JOSH: A Proposed Software Stack for the Enterprise](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/03/JOSH). There is no Java EE at all. Only **J**SON, **O**SGi, **S**cala and **H**TTP. It's quite interesting...